# How to transfer file with SFTP using OpenSSH in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, sftp, openssh

In my project I have to use OpenSSH `sftp` tool to transfer file using SFTP and it should be executed from SSIS. I searched a lot from last one month but not able to find any solution. I did transfer file using WinSCP from SSIS, but client is now switching to OpenSSH.

Anyone have any idea about transferring file using OpenSSH? It will be a great help if anyone have any solution.

I am transferring single files and I want both upload and download. We are using a private key to authenticate.

In WinSCP I was executing a `.bat` file which will call a `.txt` file and that `.txt` have the SFTP `put` and `get` commands.

Answer (score 1):

So I assume you have a batch file that runs WinSCP like this:

```
c:\path\to\winscp.com /script=c:\path\to\script.txt
```

And a WinSCP script `script.txt` that authenticates to an SFTP server using a private key and uploads and downloads a file:

```
open -privatekey=c:\path\to\key.ppk sftp://username@example.com/
get /remote/path/file.txt c:\local\path\file.txt
put c:\other\local\path\file2.txt /other/remote/path/file2.txt
exit
```

---

That would translate to [OpenSSH `sftp`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp) like this:

```
sftp.exe -b c:\path\to\script.txt -i c:\path\to\key.pem username@example.com
```

And a `sftp` script `script.txt` that transfers the files:

```
get /remote/path/file.txt c:\local\path\file.txt
put c:\other\local\path\file2.txt /other/remote/path/file2.txt
```

You have to use [PuTTYgen](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html) to convert your WinSCP .ppk private key to PEM format to use it with OpenSSH.

---

There's a guide for [converting OpenSSH script to WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_psftp_script_to_winscp). While that's the exact opposite of what you want, with some effort, you can still dig some ideas from it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do I need to provide full path for sftp.exe ? Like D:\openSSH\SFTP.exe

Comment: In you us the Win32-OpenSSH built-into Windows 10, you do not have to, as its folder is in Windows `PATH`.